# Adding facebook pixel to a specific page in prestashop

Tags: facebook, themes, prestashop

Hello I'm trying to add a facebook pixel to my web. I'm a really beginner with prestashop.

They told me I must add the pixel code to my theme's header.tpl file but...how can I know which is the correct file of a specific url?

In my /themes folder I have only 3 folders of themes :S

I need to find the specific file o my specific url (Im supossing that every url of my page has an unique theme file)

Answer (score 1):

Your `header.tpl` file is `your-site/themes/your-active-theme/header.tpl` file. It is used one and the same in all site pages.

You can find your active theme name in the back office `Preferences > Themes` page.

Comment: Then, if I want to get tracking from a unique url, where should I add the pixel?

For example, if I want tracking of my home page only, and the theme is used in all the web...how can I do it?

Comment: It is already implemented inside Facebook script. If you a re not sure what are you doing, you can buy a Prestashop module for it.